# Inquiry regarding multi-page capture function with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html2canvas, html2pdf

I am implementing a function to save a web page as a PDF using html2canvas, but the captured image is cut off in the middle because the web page content is long. How can I solve this? I want the image to fit perfectly on each screen without being interrupted.

I hope the pages continue neatly without any breaks in the middle.